# Get mouse coordinates using MouseListener with two classes

Tags: java, swing, coordinates, mouselistener

I need help with to get the x and y coorinates of my mouseclick. I have decribed place and named place dialogs who saves the information by the Plats-object which is another class. I need their coordinates depending on where you click on the panel. How can my class Plats get the x and y coordinates for the mouseclick? This is my superclass

```
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Use SwingUtilities class. It has method

```
public static Point convertPoint(Component source,int x, int y,Component destination)
```

The source is the `MouseEvent mev.getSource()` destination is the target component.

Also you can use

```
public static void convertPointToScreen(Point p,Component c)
```

if you need screen coordinates